# Open all but one buffer in a separate tab

Tags: buffers

I have following in my `~/.vimrc` to make sure that nerdtree opens for every tab:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

I also have this in the `~/.vimrc` to make sure that every new buffer opens in its own tab:

```
au BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball
```

At the moment, I'm trying to learn Go programming on vim and have installed `vim-go` plugin. What happens is that if I hit `Ctrl`+`]` to open the definition for identifier under the cursor, vim *does* open it in a new tab but nerdtree disappears from all tabs.

If I hit `<F2>` in the very first tab that was opened by vim, nerdtree opens just fine. But in the subsequent tabs, `<F2>` causes nerdtree to open in its own tab (it opens a scratch tab with just nerdtree).

How do I make sure that nerdtree opens just fine always? I don't need to open nerdtree by default for every tab or every time I open vim. But I need to hit `<F2>` to open it up so that I can open other files when needed.

Comment: I don't have a solution to your problem, but as someone who 1) has spent some time trying to fight against NERDTree to make it work how I wanted 2) has been on this site for a while and have seen a lot of new Vimmers fighting against this plugin, I would advise you to read [this](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) and not to waste your time with NERDTree: you will probably never make it work as you want and eventually you'll realize there are much better tools to use. Still I hope someone on here can find a solution to your problem :)

Comment: Also `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree` only executes `:NERDTree` once after vim has started so I don't think it has anything to do with opening NERDTree for every tabs. See [`:h VimEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) for more details.

Comment: To reiterate what @statox said, NERDTree is a good plugin if you don't *ever* try to change any of its behavior. Judging from your affinity to tree-style file viewer and using tabs instead of buffers ([here's a blog talking about this case](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/)), I'm assuming you're a new Vim user. So, if you don't mind, I'd suggest trying out more "vimmy" file browsers like [vim-dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish). There is also netrw plugin shipped with Vim, which also has tree style view. BTW, netrw is also not that great.

Comment: And, you should consider using the issue tracker of the plugin itself for issues regarding using a plugin.

Comment: @statox thanks for sharing your wisdom! I'll admit that I've heard similar opinions about NERDTree from others.

Comment: @klaus thanks for the link to the blog about buffers vs. tabs. I am not really a new vim user but I never explored using buffers much. The blog you shared was very helpful and I've adopted the "Solution 1" there for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh and I have removed the NERDTree plugin for now to see how well/bad it suits me.